# How can display text content itself using PHP from Azure File with Azure storage account?

Tags: php, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I have been installed the git lib from https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php .

I able to figure out the create file, download file, delete file.

But how can get the file content of the file and display on browser ?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of file is it?

Comment: @GauravMantri , it could be text file (.txt), pdf, or image file. 
Is it possible to echo the .txt file content from Azure file on the browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that much knowledgeable about PHP but I believe the SDK method you would want to use is [`getBlob`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/src/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php#L3702) which reads a blob and returns an object of type [`GetBlobResult`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/src/Blob/Models/GetBlobResult.php).

Contents of the blob can be read using [`getContentStream()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/src/Blob/Models/GetBlobResult.php#L118) method there.

---

If you're using Azure Files, more or less the approach would remain the same. You would be calling [`getFile`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/azure-storage-file/src/File/FileRestProxy.php#L1753) method which reads a file and returns an object of type [`GetFileResult`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/azure-storage-file/src/File/Models/GetFileResult.php).

Contents of the file can be read using [`getContentStream()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/azure-storage-file/src/File/Models/GetFileResult.php#L118) method there.

Comment: I am new to Azure and this Azure-File and Storage, is the above means that from the Azure-File I am actually unable to make the app 'read' / 'display' the 'file content' from Azure-File on browser ya ?

Comment: Updated my answer with links to reading a file in Azure File Storage. HTH.